# With virtual memory, programs running on the system can allocate far more memory than is physically available;

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

How the OS is able to do this

> With virtual memory, programs running on the system can allocate far
>   more memory than is physically available;

Answer (score 1):

It is in practice "a little more memory", not "far more memory", otherwise you are experimenting [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).

Every desktop, latop or server processor has an [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit). It is used by the [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) system to give a virtual [address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space) thru [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging) & the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache). When the kernel gets a [page fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_fault), it could fetch a page from disk -e.g. in a segment of an [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable or shared object or some other mapped file, or some pages from the swap area- or send a `SIGSEGV`  signal, see [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

On Linux, several [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) can change the address space: [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) and `munmap` (and also the obsolete `sbrk`, etc...) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html). You might advise the kernel using [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html)

You could use `cat /proc/$somepid/maps` (e.g. `cat /proc/$$/maps`  in your shell) to understand the address space map of some [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29). See [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html).

Follow all the links above and read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) and [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)