# Why does the C++ compiler create an object heap instead of pushing the class object in stack?

Tags: c++, object, heap-memory, stack-memory

On creating a class object with 'new' keyword,why is an object heap created instead of stack?Would stack not be a better option since it is faster,performs contiguous allocation and does not need manual deletion(free/delete)?
**If objects of a particular class have the same template then why do we need dynamic allocation?(justification for heap)**
[×××Please note that my doubt is not about which option a programmer must choose,but instead about why the compiler behaves the way it does in the above case.×××]

Comment: You're asking what the purpose of the heap is. Well, it's certainly possible to write applications without using the heap, but it's limiting as well; you generally have to know ahead of time every allocation you need to make. It's a trade-off between flexibility and performance.

Comment: Stack is very limited and costful.
full answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123936/why-is-there-a-stack-and-a-heap

Comment: Wow. Even the comments are duplicates. @CyberGuy wouldn't mind knowing what you mean by "costful". Stack is usually the cheaper option.

Comment: @user4581301 see image below. By costful i mean expensive in dollars.

Comment: Why is it anymore costful than the heap? Maybe we are just misinterpreting your comment.

Comment: In order to understand the stack i guess you need to learn a little bit of assembly and __cdecl calling convension otherwise nothing people say will make any sense to you anyways. The stack is limited, there are rules that needs to be followed in order to have some sense of flow and order. The heap, stack, data segment or whatever you want to call it is all in ram its just how allocation and deallocation is handled.

Comment: The `new` gets memory from the free-store.  Nothing stops an implementation from using the stack as the free-store.

Comment: Stack is usually more efficient because it requires adjusting a pointer.  Allocating from the heap usually involves find a block that is appropriate size; which takes more time than adjusting a pointer.

Comment: By the way, it's not one or the other.  Many implementations give you a stack and heap to use (as well as global variable space).  A rule of thumb is that large items (objects) use the heap.  Also, the heap is used for objects that have a longer lifetime than inside a function or inside a statement block.

Comment: On a side note, if you wanted to allocate off the stack (with auto-free on function exit), you could use _alloca(): object * pobject = (object *) _alloca(sizeof(object)); .

Comment: Strongly object to the premature closure of this question. It is not a duplicate of the question about what distinguishes stack vs heap, it is a question about why you would use one or the other. A thoughtful answer could have been given. When a question is closed this quickly though it can be answered, you waste the time of dozens of visitors and worsen this site and its rep.

Comment: I don't see how this question is a repetition of stack vs heap.I simply want to know why we use heaps when we always have the option of going with stacks for c++ objects.

Comment: Very related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3889495/214671

Answer (score 3):

Basically, stack-created objects cannot have a lifetime outside of the function they're created in. That's the most obvious rationale for a heap.

```
Object * foo()
{
  Object o;
  return &o;  // undefined behaviour, because 'o' ceases to exist once the function returns.
}
```

Comment: Note that string literals like `"Hello World"` are an exception to this rule

Comment: @Machtl, The 'string literal' isn't a stack-created object (or a heap-created one). The *pointer* to it is, though.